# Python code, IndentationError: unexpected indent 9

Tags: python

I want to compute the band structure of some model. First,I have to get the eigenvalues, and the eigenvectors by diagonalizing the 3*3 matrix.
 I dont know what mistakes I've done.
Error message
 File "", line 12
    for n in range((-L/(2.0)), (L/(2.0)):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRaFw.png)

Comment: your `for` loop is indented when it shouldn't be, as the error message states. What more info do you need?

Comment: Please, paste code as code (formatted text) not as a picture.

Answer (score -1):

As noted in the comments the for statement itself should not be indented. There is also an additional problem the for statement should end with a ':' not a ';'.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
L=20.0 #length of the chain
k= 2.0*pi*n/L
M = np.array([[-2*t*cos(k), -t, 0.0], [-t, -2*t*cos(k), -t], [0.0, -t, -2*t*cos(k)]])
for n in range((-L/(2.0)), (L/(2.0))
u, V = la.eig(M)
print(u)
print np.real_if_close(u)
```